# Program terminates when called inside main function

Tags: java, call

I am new to java programming, I have programmed in C and C++ but have moved to Java recently, So I am a bit confuse about how things are in Java. I am calling a function inside my main but the program gets terminated, I don't know why its happening and can't figure it out. Here is my program

```
package Prime;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class isprime
{
    public static boolean isPrime (int n)
    {
        int flag=0;
        for (int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(i%n==0)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        }   
        if(flag==1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        } 
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int n;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number you want to test");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.close();
    isPrime(n);
    }   
    n = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: why `n = sc.nextInt();` is outside the scope of `main()`?

Comment: `public static boolean isPrime (int n)` Why is boolean method taking an int?

Comment: because I have to return true or false

Comment: As far as I can see, this shouldn't compile at all as the assignment to `n` is outside any methods.

Comment: rakeb.mazhual its inside in my program but the editor on this website messed it up

Comment: My main is actually  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int n;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number you want to test");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    isPrime(n);
    }

Comment: whats the problem with my program

Comment: What do you mean by terminate? Were you expecting any output?

Comment: Ya probably. I am really new to java started 2 days ago, I have managed to work around a few basic things but I don't know anything and havent had anytime to read material so I was hoping to get some help here. I was expecting output in form of true or false

Answer (score 1):

- Your `n = sc.nextInt();` is outside the scope of `main()` function. Moreover your are closing the scanner first.
- You called `isPrime(n);` which returns `boolean` but you did not catch the `return` value.

You want to do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number you want to test");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();

    if (isPrime(n)) {
        System.out.println("prime");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not prime");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

**Finally**, your *prime* calculation is wrong. A prime number is divisible by itself, so change

```
for (int i=2;i<=n;i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=2;i < n;i++)
              ^^^
```